# Java create ssl socket using byte array as certificate

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, network-programming, ssl-certificate

I've got a byte arrray containing the client certificate and a byte array with the password.

How can I create an SSL socket with these two arrays?

I've already searched for tutorials but it seems these plain SSLSockets aren't really well documented.